# Change wifi adapter name shown in settings Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, gnome, settings, customization

I have 3 wifi adapters installed on my laptop.
On Settings, under Wifi, I can see all 3 of them but I am not able to change the name they display (in the case of the second adapter, the name is so big that makes the opened window to grow all the way to my second monitor).

See picture attached.

[image: Wifi adapter names shown in settings screenshot]

Is there a way to rename them?
Besides that, I would like to hide the Broadcom adapter if possible (it is already blacklisted).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Those long names that you show us are a function of hardware and driver software, and really can't be changed easily. Is there any specific reason why you have/need three wi-fi adapters on a laptop?

Comment: I have a OSX system also installed so I added two extra mini pci adapters so I can have wifi and bluetooth enabled for that particular system (since the Intel adapter is not compatible). I would like to manage the way Ubuntu display those names if it's possible.

Comment: I'm not aware of how to do that. Sorry.